# Javascript is changing in Content Editor WebPart

Tags: javascript, content-editor-web-part

I want to add this a Widget in my sharepoint site.
But every time someone edit the page, it mess the script.
Someome knows why sharepoint is changing the script? And how to avoid it?

The script that I inserted in a Content Editor Webpart is :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.widgetserver.com/syndication/subscriber/InsertWidget.js"></script><script type="text/javascript">if (WIDGETBOX) WIDGETBOX.renderWidget('842855a7-ddc9-4cbf-8e46-9974f1190833');</script><noscript><a href="http://www.ricardo-vargas.com/pt/podcasts">Acesse o site</a></noscript>
```

It is like the script get duplicated, and I need to clean everything and copy the script of the widget again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to store that content in a Document Library somewhere and simply use the Content Link to point to that .js file from the Document library.

It is some kind of security measure introduced in the SharePoint 2010

Comment: Hum... I thought on something like that. So it is a security measure.

Comment: Ok. I created a html file where I inserted the script, and with the Content Editor Webpart pointed to that html file. And the problem dind't occurred anymore. Thanks.